# Make buttons stick to bottom of page *BUT* respect scrolling

Tags: css, css-position, wizard

I'm basically trying to add three wizard-like "step" buttons that (to me) naturally belong at the bottom of the page - "PREVIOUS" |  "NEXT"  |  "FINISH". The three buttons are in a single div.  The buttons need to always be at the bottom of the screen AND always at the end of the HTML content.

I've seen partial solutions to this that try to use **position:fixed** and that works fine if I have less a page worth of text to scroll through in the wizard - the buttons appear at the bottom of the screen using bottom:0px.  But the problem is that sometimes I have a lot of text in the window and I need to scroll down quite some distance.  I don't want to see the three wizard buttons until I get to the bottom.

I think basically, I sort of want to apply a conditional margin to my div, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here's a fiddle that doesn't work to show what I'm trying:

```
[https://codepen.io/RiverTaig/pen/xzaVxX][1]
```

Comment: Here's a non-working fiddle that tries to use absolute positioning - as you can see, on 
 a big page the text overlaps the wizard buttons at the bottom. 
 https://codepen.io/RiverTaig/pen/xzaVxX

Comment: Here's the working solution where the wizard buttons always appear at the bottom of the HTML content and at the bottom of the page. https://codepen.io/RiverTaig/pen/xzaVxX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `height` of `#smallPage` in `vh` using `calc`.
Remove the `css` of `.wizard`

```js
var i = 0;
function toggle() {
  var smallEl = document.getElementById("smallPage");
  var bigEl = document.getElementById("bigPage");
  if (i === 0) {
    smallEl.style.display = "none";
    bigEl.style.display = "";
    i = 1;
  } else {
    smallEl.style.display = "0";
    bigEl.style.display = "none";
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.relative{
  width:200px;
  
}
.wizard{
  
}

.content {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 60px); /* Change as per your requirement */
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <button onclick="toggle()">TOGGLE</button>
  <div id="smallPage" class="content">
    This has just a tiny amount of text and won't cause the page to scroll.  Click the toggle button at the top to hide this div and load one with a lot more text. Hopefully the three buttons -  "PREVIOUS", "NEXT", and "FINISH" - will still stay at the bottom! 
  </div>
  <div id="bigPage" style="display:none">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur
  </div>  
  <div class="wizard">
    <button>Prev</button>
    <button>Next</button>
    <button>Finish</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please let me know if you need any clarification @DevonTaig

Answer (score 0):

Give your wizard container a fixed height. For our example, let that height is 100px. Now give it a fixed position like this:

```
.wizard-container {
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; /* this property and value may depend on you design */
}
```

Now give your document container a `margin-bottom` of 100px (equivalent to the height of the `.wizard-container`)

As per my understanding this is the solution of your problem. Let me know if that doesn't help.

Respects

Comment: Also consider the `postition: sticky;` It is now available on major browser. It will sticky the div at the edges of the browser until arrive it's scroll to the insertion position and it will scroll with the content.